# Qt How to check state checkbox in QtableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qcheckbox

Recently I found the way that checkbox places in the middle of QtableWidget item.
However, I do not know how to check state whether or not button is clicked.
Could you tell me how to check button state?

here is what Ive found code:

```
QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget();
QCheckBox *pCheckBox = new QCheckBox();
QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
pCheckBox->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
pLayout->addWidget(pCheckBox);
pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
pLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
ui->tableWidget2->setCellWidget(2,2, pWidget);
```

Comment: any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is very late you can solve it like this:

```
auto field = ui->tableWidget2->cellWidget(2, 2, pWidget);

std::cout << qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(field)->isChecked() << std::endl;
```

This works for other types as well (QComboBox etc.). Although it would probably be better to just use the checkbox functionality that `QTableWidgetItem` already has.

This example might not work if you are using a tristate checkbox in which case you should call: `checkState()` and compare it to `Qt::CheckState`. If `qobject_cast<T>` does not work out you can use a `reinterpret_cast<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created your checkboxes in the QWidgetTable like this:

```
int row...;int column...;
...
QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
checkBoxItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
ui->Table->setItem(row, column, checkBoxItem);
```

You can check the status of the item that corresponds to your widget in another function like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_Table_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{
    QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxState = ui->Table->item(row, column);

    if(ui->Table->item(row,column)->checkState())
    {
        checkBoxState->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
        ui->Table->setItem(row, column, checkBoxState);
    }
    else
    {
        checkBoxState->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
        ui->Table->setItem(row, column, checkBoxState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, why are you creating a new `QTableWIdgetItem`?

Comment: change `QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxState = new QTableWidgetItem();` to `QTableWidgetItem *checkBoxState = ui->Table->item(row, column);`

Comment: can you tell how can we check type of cell that its checkbox or text field etc

Comment: I think you didn't know realize the special point of this question, the special point is using `setCellWidget` to set item instead of using `ui->Table->setItem` to set item , i didn't test it, but i guess in this way, `ui->Table->item(row, column)` will return something that you didn't expected.